# Maximizing entropy for sum of random variables

Tags: references, conditional-probability, entropy, information-theory

**Problem Setting**

Let $X_1, X_2,\cdots,X_m$ be identical and marginally $Bern(p=0.5)$ random variables. There is no restriction on the joint distribution of $X_1, X_2,\cdots,X_m$.

**Observation**

The entropy $H(X_1, X_2,\cdots,X_m)$ is maximized (over all possible joint distributions) when $X_i's$ are independent. This can be proved by expanding the entropy term using [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy#Chain_rule)

**Question**

Is the entropy of their sum, $S=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_m$ also maximized when they are independent?

Comment: Are we seeking to maximize the entropy (of the sum) over all possible joint distributions of $X_1,\ldots,X_m$ with the condition that the marginals need to be $Bern(0.5)$?

Comment: @Juho: Yes. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**. The entropy of $S = X_1 + X_2+\cdots+X_m$ is maximized when $S$ is a uniformly distributed in $[m].$

Example for $m = 2$

$$
P(X_1 = 0, X_2 = 0 ) = 1/3 \\
P(X_1 = 1, X_2 = 0 ) = 1/6 \\
P(X_1 = 0, X_2 = 1 ) = 1/6 \\
P(X_1 = 1, X_2 = 1 ) = 1/3
$$
Tha above joint distribution in $X_1$, $X_2$ has the highest entropy for  $H(X_1 +X_2)$. Also, by symmetry,  $X_1$, $X_2$ are indentically distributed in the above distribution.